# Using href tag to directly download an image

Tags: javascript

I have two options for the user to open an image:

1) Directly download the image which is returned from my aspx request - NOT WORKING.

2) Just open the original (higher quality) image in a new tab - WORKING FINE.

This snippet below points to an INTERNAL SERVER, so it doesn't work on this environment.

```html
<div class="modal-header">
    <a
      type="image/jpg"            
      [href]="theImage.CompUrl"
      title="Save Image"
      download="img_{{ theImage.UID }}.jpg"
    >
      <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
      [href]="originImgUrl"
      title="Open Original Image"
      target="_blank"
    >
      <i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

The first href also contains the `download` attribute, but since the URL is not directly referencing the jpg image it is opening the returned image to a new tab.

The rendered html is show below:

```html
<div _ngcontent-c40="" class="modal-content">
 <div _ngcontent-c40="" class="modal-header ng-star-inserted">
  <a _ngcontent-c40="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
   type="image/jpg" 
   href="https://Server01.DomainName.com/Folder1234/TheServer.aspx?s=33333444445555a&amp;m=comp&amp;id=1330849" 
   title="Export Image" download="img_1330849.jpg">
   <i _ngcontent-c40="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
  </a>
  <a _ngcontent-c40="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" target="_blank" type="button" 
   href="https://Server01.DomainName.com/Folder1234/TheServer.aspx?s=cc4444444423aa&amp;m=org&amp;id=1330849" 
    title="Export Original Image">
    <i _ngcontent-c40="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-share"></i></a>
    <button _ngcontent-c40="" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way around this where I can directly download the image in my first request ?

Comment: Your code snippets don't work

Comment: @NinoFiliu - I'm sorry.  My href points to an internal server, so I'm thinking how I can post a live example.

Comment: Have you tried this? [Force download with JavaScript](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-download)

Comment: @k3lly.dev - looks promising. I'll let you know.

Comment: @bob.mazzo alright, let me know if it helped you out.

Comment: If I assign the full request URL to that `data` var, or to the `a.href` property in the `downloadFile` function. i.e. `a.href =  "blob:" + urlToImage` - it will attempt to download something but throws an error that the format is not supported.

Comment: Maybe I just need to dump the result image to a hidden canvas first before downloading....

Answer (score 0):

The permanent solution is to add the `Content-Disposition` response header from the server - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition. Once we add this to the server side, then we can make a request for the attachment.

In the meantime, I am just writing the image data to a hidden canvas then using `toDataURL` Canvas API:

In Angular component:

```js
const hiddenCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
hiddenCanvas.width = this.imageObj.width;
hiddenCanvas.height = this.imageObj.height;
this.ctxHidden = hiddenCanvas.getContext("2d");
this.ctxHidden.drawImage(this.imageObj, 0, 0);
this.saveImgSrc = hiddenCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
this.printImg.nativeElement.src = this.saveImgSrc; // displayed in modal-body
```

```html
<div *ngIf="printModalType == 'export'" class="modal-header">
        <a
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
          href="{{ saveImgSrc }}"
          title="Save image"
          download="img_{{ theImage.UID }}.jpg"
        >
          <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
</div>
```